# Chrome with google search causes original tab got changed

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-search

I don't know which setting make this happen.

I set google search setting -> search result click causing new tab

somebody know that situation?

This is very annoying..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

click: google.com/preferences

make sure that the box "open each selected result in a new browser window" is NOT marked

save changes

Comment: or this is the direct link if you are unable to find: https://www.google.com/preferences

Comment: you don't want new tab to be opened when you click any link from google search